# How to get the span of an element in a list after we extract the sublist from the larger list?

Tags: python, list

Let me elaborate on the title.

I have a list like this:

```
some_list = ['The', 'efficacy', 'and', 'safety', 'of', 'a', 'new', 'benzodiazepine', 'antagonist', ',', 
 'flumazenil', ',', 'were', 'assessed', 'in', 'a', 'double', '-', 'blind', 'multicenter', 'study', '.', 
'Flumazenil', '(', 'mean', 'dose', ',', '0', '.', '76', 'mg', ')', 'or', 'placebo', '(', 'mean', 'dose', ',', 
'8', '.', '9', 'ml', ')', 'was', 'administered', 'intravenously', 'to', '130', 'and', '67', 'patients', ',', 
'respectively', ',', 'who', 'had', 'been', 'given', 'diazepam', 'in', 'conjunction', 'with', 'an', 'opioid', '(', 
'fentanyl', ',', 'meperidine', ',', 'or', 'morphine', ')', 'for', 'the', 
'induction', 'and', 'maintenance', 'of', 'intravenous', 'conscious', 'sedation', 'for', 'diagnostic', 'or', 
'therapeutic', 'surgical', 'procedures', '.']
```

This is basically a string from a medical document. The entity in question is `'flumazenil'`. Right now in `some_list`, the "span" of `'flumazenil'` is 10-11 (i.e., `some_list[10:11] = 'flumazenil'`).

What I'm doing is extracting a sublist from the larger list, but the problem is I want to adjust the index to match the newly extracted list. For example:

```
some_sublist = ['flumazenil', ',', 'were', 'assessed', 'in', 'a', 'double', '-', 'blind', 'multicenter', 'study', 
'.', 'Flumazenil', '(', 'mean', 'dose', ',',  '0', '.', '76', 'mg', ')', 'or', 'placebo', '(', 'mean', 'dose', ',', 
'8', '.', '9', 'ml', ')', 'was', 'administered']
```

`some_sublist` starts at the 10th index of `some_list` and ends at the 43rd index. `'flumazenil'`'s new span index would be `0:1`.

I've thought of using something like:

```
def get_new_span(l1, l2):
    l2_start_idx = l1.index(l2)
    adjustment_length = len(l1[:l2_start_idx].split())

    return adjustment_length


new_span = [idx - adjustment_length for idx in old_span]
```

But I'm wondering if there may be a better way or a built-in function/library that I could be using. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the index of the word in the new list, why not just use `new_idx = some_sublist.find("flumazenil")`

Sorry if  this doesn't help it's just I'm not sure what it is that you need them to have the same index for, or why there is a sublist created in the first place.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) and [`str.index`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) are pretty much the same thing.